# Displaying ALL data from sql table in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

When I print my code it only prints the question and description of id = 1 but not the rest of the table.

here is my code.

Please show me how to print my entire table which has like 20 questions or so...and also please show me how to make it so that the questions stay on the browser (even when I refresh the page) because currently the data does not stay on the browser when i refresh the page.

Thanks So Much!

```
<?php

require_once "connection.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME );

    if($conn->connect_error) {

        die("connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else {

        echo "Submit button connected to database!";
    }

    $question = $_POST['question'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    $sql = " INSERT INTO `ask` (question_id, question, description) VALUES
    (NULL, '{$question}', '{$description}' ) ";

    if($conn->query($sql)) {

        echo "it worked";
    } else {

        echo "error: " . $conn->error;

        exit();
    }


    $query = "SELECT * FROM `ask` ";

    if( $result = $conn->query($query)) {
        $fetch = $result->fetch_assoc();

        echo "<p>{$fetch['question']}</p>";
        echo "<p>{$fetch['description']}</p>";

    } else {
        echo "failed to fetch array";
    }






}


?>
```

Comment: You're only retrieving the first row of your result set. You need a loop to retrieve all the rows. There are many, many tutorials on this - go find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a for each loop:

```
    <?php

require_once "connection.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME );

    if($conn->connect_error) {

        die("connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else {

        echo "Submit button connected to database!";
    }

    $question = $_POST['question'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    $sql = " INSERT INTO `ask` (question_id, question, description) VALUES
    (NULL, '{$question}', '{$description}' ) ";

    if($conn->query($sql)) {

        echo "it worked";
    } else {

        echo "error: " . $conn->error;

        exit();
    }


    $query = "SELECT * FROM `ask` ";

    if( $result = $conn->query($query)) {
        $fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
        foreach($fetch as $ques) {
            echo "<p>" . $ques['question'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p>" . $ques['description'] . "</p>";
        }

    } else {
        echo "failed to fetch array";
    }






}


?>
```

All I've done there is change:

```
$fetch = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo "<p>{$fetch['question']}</p>";
echo "<p>{$fetch['description']}</p>";
```

to:

```
$fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
foreach($fetch as $ques) {
    echo "<p>" . $ques['question'] . "</p>";
    echo "<p>" . $ques['description'] . "</p>";
}
```

Comment: Hi there is an error that states Warning: Illegal string offset 'question' in C:\xampp\htdocs\homepage\home.php on line 39
2


Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in C:\xampp\htdocs\homepage\home.php on line 40
2


Warning: Illegal string offset 'question' in C:\xampp\htdocs\homepage\home.php on line 39
h


Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in C:\xampp\htdocs\homepage\home.php on line 40
h


Warning: Illegal string offset 'question' in C:\xampp\htdocs\homepage\home.php on line 39
h


Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in C:\xampp\htdocs\homepage\home.php on line

Comment: This means that for some reason, you are only getting one row. So $ques is ending up as a string rather than an array. Have you definitely used mysql_fetch_array rather than just fetch_assoc?

Answer (score 0):

fetch_assoc() — Fetch a result row as an associative array

so it gets only 1 row you need to loop through the rest of the rows check the examples [reference from php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)